# Order summary messed up in Magento 2 checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, blocks

On my magento 2 store, order summary is messed up in checkout page, please give me a solution for this, please check the picture for example.[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Fix this issue,

just add the below code your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module> ModPagespeed off </IfModule>
```